# Android single activity with multiple functions and multiple layout files valid or not?

Tags: android, layout

I have an activity with three different operations
-add
-view
-edit
I am using single activity for this and on calling i change the view by calling setContentView(xml_file_for_that_function). It works fine but as i have also just hearded about fragments and thinks it's a better approach.
I just want to ask experienced ones that IS IT VALID WHAT I AM DOING or i have to use fragments and having different xml layout for differnet functions within same activity is not a valid android approach. i.e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is a valid approach to the problem, the usual way of dealing with it is in fact with fragments

If you need some help on how to use fragments here is a good tutorial from the android dev site http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html